# Create a new list of dictionaries within a new dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and need to create a new one that contains new keys and also keys&values from my original dictionary. One of the keys will have to contain a list of dictionaries (those would be the values from original dictionary)
My data looks like the following:

```
data = [{'CloseDate': '2020-05-01',
  'OpportunityID': '1',
  'CustomerID': '10'},
 {'CloseDate': '2020-07-31',
  'OpportunityID': '2',
  'CustomerID': '11'}]
```

I want my new list of dicts look like this:

```
new_data = [{'id': '39',
           'Query': [{'records': '40', 'Order Name': '1', 'CustomerID': '10'}]},
           {'id': '39',
           'Query': [{'records': '40', 'Order Name': '2', 'CustomerID': '11'}]}]
```

I have tried the following:

```
new_data = []

for item in data: 
    params_dict = {}
    params_dict["id"] = "39"
    params_dict["Query"] = []
    # push new_dicts in params_dict
    new_dict = {}
    new_dict["records"] = "40"
    new_dict["Order Name"] = data["OpportunityID"]
    params_dict.append(new_dict)
    new_data.append(params_dict)
```

Error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: What's new_dict? It's not defined. Which line is giving you TypeError?

Comment: as you iterated through data using item, 9th line doesnt need data but item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to iterate through `item` and not `data` inside the loop.
Also you need to append to `Query`.
Try:

```
new_data = []

for item in data: 
    params_dict = {}
    params_dict["id"] = "39"
    params_dict["Query"] = []
    new_dict = {} # defined new_dict
    new_dict["records"] = "40"
    new_dict["Order Name"] = item["OpportunityID"] # here it should be item
    params_dict["Query"].append(new_dict)
    new_data.append(params_dict)
```

Also:

```
new_data = []

for item in data: 
    params_dict = {}
    params_dict["id"] = "39"
    params_dict["Query"] = [{"records" : "40","Order Name" :item["OpportunityID"] }]
    new_data.append(params_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you, Joshua. I have tried to run the code and have `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
on line  `params_dict.append(new_dict)`

Comment: why define a new dict in the loop and not just set values in the `params_dict`? also your solution has an error

Comment: @gold_cy now is it ok?

Comment: @Chique_Code use `new_dict["Order Name"] = 'Forecast Placeholder -'  + item["OpportunityID"]`

Answer (score 2):

```py
datas_list=[]
for get_dict in data:
    new_dict={}
    new_dict["id"] = 39
    new_dict['Query']=[]
    other_dictionary={}
    other_dictionary['records']=40
    for values in get_dict:
        if values == "OpportunityID":
            other_dictionary['Order Name'] = get_dict[values]
        if values == "CustomerID" :
            other_dictionary[values] = get_dict[values]
    new_dict["Query"].append(other_dictionary)
    datas_list.append(new_dict)
```